# Unable to store appended data into array

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi here is a jquery function i am working on i have appended a particular div. The div has 2 inputs I am trying to capture the input values in data_to_send array but it only captures one input because the names are not unique.

```
function() {
        $('#si-goal-link-btn').click(function() {
            $('#si-goal-links').append('<div class="goal-link si-goal"><label for="iconURL">Icon URL</label><input class="si-goal-link form-control" type="file" name="iconURL"><br><label for="title">Title</label><input type="text" placeholder="Enter title" class="si-goal-link form-control" name="title"><br><hr></div>')
        })

        $('form #si-btn').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault()
            var self = $(this)
            var data_to_send  = {}

            $('form').find('.si-input').each(function() {
                if ( $(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
                    if ($(this).hasClass('si-wysiwyg')){
                        data_to_send[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).code()
                    }

                    if ($(this).hasClass('si-goal-link')) {
                        //UNABLE TO STORE THE VALUE HERE
                        data_to_send[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
                    } 

                    data_to_send[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()
                }
            })

            var url = $('form').data('si-location')
            $.post(url, data_to_send, function(data) {

            })

        })
    }
```

How do i capture this data and store it as an array within an array over here ?

Comment: Any reason you are not simply using [`serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) for this …?

Comment: K i ll give it a try

Comment: Is `$(this).code()` from a plugin?

Answer (score 0):

To get array-within-array-like behavior in Javascript, you will need to make an array a property of your data object, and then `push()` the same named values onto that array.

```
var data_to_send  = {};
data_to_send.si-goal-link = [];

//inside loop or wherever is needed
data_to_send.si-goal-link.push($(this).val());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 $.post(url, $('form').serialize(), function(data) {

 })
```

Comment: To be helpful, please add an explanation to your post.